# jQuery Widgets not working on tabs loaded by Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-events

I have an application that has many tabs, apart from the first tab - all others are loaded via Ajax.

The tab content all loads correctly.
However if I have a jQuery widget in a (ajax loaded) tab, the widget does not work.

I attempted to use:

```
$(document).on('click', '#dateOfBirth', function() {
    $( '#dateOfBirth' ).datepicker();
});
```

But the datepicker does not display.

Confusingly (for me):

```
$(document).on('click', '#dateOfBirth', function() {
    alert('This works properly');
});
```

Works properly! The alert displays when the date field is "clicked".
And of course if I have a simple page without the tabs / ajax content - the datepicker displays as expected when the date field is clicked.

I am using the jQuery 2.2.0 and
jQuery UI 1.12.0 with the "redmond" theme / CSS.

The view html follows the following;

```
<div class = "emr-bodycontent">
  <div id="tabs">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#tabs-1">Patient Details</a></li>
      <li><a href="@emr.controllers.pas.routes.CarerDetails.carerDetails()">Carers</a></li>
...
...
```

Here is the JS used for the TABS;

```
$( "#tabs" ).tabs({
    beforeLoad: function( event, ui ) {
        ui.jqXHR.fail(function() {
            ui.panel.html(
                "There seems to be an error retrieving the data you requested."
            );
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: It could be because of the datepicker's own code. The only thing I can think of is maybe the datepicker somehow initializes itself with existing DOM elements on page load, so if you load more elements with ajax, it doesn't know about them yet?

Comment: Are there any errors in the console log??

Comment: show us your ajax loading code. Plugins need to be initialized when the elements exist. So if you load new elements...means new initialization in ajax callback. `event delegation` is different ...and that's why alert works

Comment: The only problem that I can guess is that, the datepicker() function might have some problem with the information that you have given.....

Comment: And another thing what is `#dateOfBirth`?? Is it a div, select, date,input??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, thanks very much for the answers / comments.

Both answers work successfully.
Kieran's worked straight away as it was manually triggering the event.

Charlie's worked, too - but only after I clicked several times.

Though after fixing my underlying issue, Charlie's worked straight away, too.

**The underlying issue was indeed a duplicate ID.**
(thanks for the prompt to check, Charlie).

Because the TAB contents are their own individual forms / pages - I only ever worried about making ID's unique within individual TABs.

After ensuring that ALL IDs are unique, the widget works correctly / as expected.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using `click` use `focus` and datepicker will work . Assumes that the element id is valid and is an input

```
$(document).on('focus', '#dateOfBirth', function() {
    $( '#dateOfBirth' ).datepicker();
});
```

For any other plugins inside tabs you can use `load` callback of tabs ... see api docs

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/aHV9pEGrQFN21gaTZOx9?p=preview)**</kbd>

Comment: I tried this, too - just for my own learning - unfortunately changing it to focus from click - does not display the datepicker widget, within my tab.

Comment: Not sure what to tell you since I've shown it to work in ajax loaded situation. Can check if element exists inside tabs `load` callback. Can also initialize it there

Comment: also...do you have duplicates for that ID? If so switch to using class

Answer (score 1):

I will suggest you to setup the `datepicker()` after Ajax content loaded, do not use click event. Because the initiate call of `$('#dateOfBirth').datepicker()` is to set up the datepicker, you may need to click again to trigger the calendar.

Or, you can try to manually trigger it right after set.

```
$(document).on('click', '#dateOfBirth', function() {
  $(this).datepicker();
  $(this).datepicker("show");
 });
```